# Class definition and utilization errors

Tags: c++, syntax

I am getting errors with the following code. The errors are `incomplete type is not allowed` and `use of undefined type 'mGame'`.

header.h:

```
//--Libraries
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//--Classes
class mGame;
```

Game.cc:

```
#include "header.h"

class mGame
{
private:

public:
    bool intro();
};
```

Intro.cc:

```
#include "header.h"

bool mGame::intro() //--Line 3
{
    printf("|-----------------------------|\n");

    printf("\n Welcome to the Guessing Game!\n");

    printf("\n|-----------------------------|\n");
    return false;
}
```

The errors are both on line 3 of intro.cc. I tried finding a solution, but I couldn't for what I am doing.

Comment: Your `game.cc` should be a `game.h`.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `mGame` from `Intro.cc`, you have to move the class declaration into `header.h` (or into some other header file that you include from `Intro.cc`).

Having a forward declaration in `header.h` is not enough (that's what is meant by "incomplete type is not allowed").

Comment: So, I can only put class declarations in a header file and I can only use forward declarations for functions? Is it possible to have a forward declaration in some way?

Comment: If you want your classes usable from multiple translation units, you put their declarations into header files. You *can* forward-declare classes. However, you're severely restricted as to what you can do with such a class until the compiler sees the full declaration.

Comment: It's adviced to do that, but has nothing to do with the actual error.

Comment: @Pon-3: You must have recursive #includes somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

header.h doesn't know any definitions of game.cc, you tell header.h only, that there is a class mGame. rename game.cc to game.h and include it into header.h and delete the line "class mGame;"

Comment: I think it's because of your "#include "header.h"" in the 'new' "game.h". To avoid such errors, you could start a header file (like game.h) with a "#ifndef GAME_H" next line: "#define GAME_H" and an "#endif" at the last line of the header file, which means, that the header will be included only once.